# Is there a non-static ClassInitialize alternative in MSTest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 test framework (I guess that's MSTest). I have some code that I need to run **once and only once** before the various testmethods run. ClassInitialize seemed perfect until I learned that it must be static.

First, I have an instance variable for ChromeDriver:

```
private ChromeDriver driver;
```

I think I need to have something like this, but nonstatic:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void Initialize() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("test-type");
    options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
    options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;
    driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\MyStuff", options);
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
}
```

The above does not compile because class instances are being newed up inside this static method. But I'm forced to make it static, or runtime errors result saying "this has to be a static method" and "wrong signature", etc.

If I spin up my ChromeDriver (declared as a class variable) either in the class constructor or in a TestInitialize method, everything works fine BUT **a new browser window opens for each and every test**. So when I have 50 test methods I'm going to have 50 instances of Chrome opened, and that's bad.

I just want to reuse my `driver` instance for every test and not have to spin up a new one each time, which opens a new browser.

How can this be done?

Comment: Well you could make `driver` a static variable...

Comment: You are right, that works perfectly. I should have thought of that. Want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's really the *best* approach, but you could make it a static variable - it's fine to access static variables from instance methods (your tests) after all.

Note that this could cause problems if you try to run your tests in parallel, however. It's probably worth investigating what the test instance lifecycle is - where you can use one *instance* for multiple tests, in which case initializing the instance variable in the constructor might be another reasonable approach.

(Unless it actually takes a long time to initialize the driver, I'd be tempted to create it on a per-test basis anyway...)

Comment: The static variable solves it perfectly. Per-test creation of ChromeDriver is very bad because it spawns a brand new browser window for each test. As mentioned in the original post, auto-launching a few hundred browser windows on a single machine is really bad. It will crash the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your test class contains 10 tests. For a proper test, your test should not be influenced by other tests, nor should your test influence others.

To enforce this, the developers of the unit tests defined that every test runs in its own test class object. This gives you freedom to change variables in your test class object without influencing other tests.

You want your initializer to be run only once and that all tests use the same variables. Each test runs in its own test object, hence these variables must be in something common. The easiest method for this is a static variable.

However, if you prefer not to use static variables, consider using [the singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The one-and-only singleton object contains the variables you want to initialize before any of your tests start.

```
private class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleTon GetInstance()
    {
        if (theOneAndOnlyInstance == null)
        {
            theOneAndOnlyInstance = new MySingleton(...);
        }
        return theOneAndOnlyInstance;
    }

    private static MySingleton theOneAndOnlyInstance = null;

    private MySingleton(...)
    {
        ... // initialize the non-static test variables
    }

    #region test variables
    public int TestVariableX {get; set;}
    ...
    #endregion test variables
}

[TestMethod}
public void MyTest()
{
    var myTestVariables = MySingleton.GetInstance(); 
    ...
}
```

The advantage is that the test variables are not created nor initialized before anyone uses them. The constructor is private, so the only one who can create the object is the static function GetInstance().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is the best approach, but seems like it works.
The only thing you need here is unique test methods names part.

```
    private const string TEST_METHOD_UNIQUE_NAME_PART = "test";
    private static TestContext _testContext;
    private static bool _isPreconditionCompleted;
    private static int _numberOfCompletedTests;

    private int NumberOfTestMethodsInClass
    {
        get
        {
            var className = _testContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName.Split('.').Last().Trim();
            var currentType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
                             .Where(r => r.Name.Trim() == className).First();

            return currentType.GetMethods().Where(r => r.Name.ToLower()
                  .Contains(TEST_METHOD_UNIQUE_NAME_PART)).Count();
        }
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassSetUp(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
        _isPreconditionCompleted = false;
        _numberOfCompletedTests = 0;
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        if (!_isPreconditionCompleted)
        {
            PreConditionMethod();
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _numberOfCompletedTests++;

        if (_numberOfCompletedTests == NumberOfTestMethodsInClass)
        {
            PostConditionMethod();
        }
    }

    private void PreConditionMethod()
    {
        // Your code
        _isPreconditionCompleted = true;
    }

    private void PostConditionMethod()
    {
        // Your code
    }
```